# Serve different login depending on device

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, include

I'm building a web app (LAMP - AJAX) consisting two separate versions, one for desktop clients and one for mobile devices. I'd like to serve up a different login page from the root depending on which device they are using and was thinking of using a conditional redirect.

My question is.. will this cause unnecessary delay to the end user and/or bad look bad from an SEO point of view? IS there a way to seamlessly serve up the content from the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a php conditional include based on the device used using [this](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect) code along the lines of

```
if($device->isMobile()){
include("mobilelogin.php");
}else{
include("desktoplogin.php");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The delay for a redirect is not significant enough to be an issue for the user.

For the SEO part, if you need to be authenticated to use the app then there is no SEO, search engines not being able to index your pages.

If you don't need to be authenticated, then why not use a hidden input in you log in form that tells you the device the user is using.

Or, if your only concern is the website looking good for every device, I think responsive design is a better choice than 2 different website layouts.

*Also I learned just now that "authentified" is not an english word, "authenticated" is :)*

Comment: Very good point about SEO! I ended up going for a separate form depending on the device. I know responsive design is probably nicer in the long run and may well change in future. Thanks.